# Retain scroll position after new items added to angular collection ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scroll

We're creating chat in our project and get issue with messages loading when user scrolls top. We need create something like infinite scroll but when user scrolls top. The main issue we get is - when we get new X messages and unshift it to collection scroll position always gets top. How we can retain scroll position after each new element is added to collection ?
Our code is simple ng-repeat in html and ajax call in controller.

Html structure:

```
<div class="messages-view-bg messages-list-container has-footer" ng-class="{'searching' : showSearchBar}" id="userMessagesView" style="height: {{deviceHeight-75}}px">
<div class="row" ng-if="conversation.description !== undefined" style="text-align: center; color: grey">
<p style="width: 100%">{{conversation.description}}</p>
</div>
<div class="conversation-bubble" in-view="$inview && $index == 1 && loadmore()" ng-repeat="message in messages track by $index" id="msg-{{message.id}}">
</div>
{{message.content}}
</div>
```

method what loads new messages:

```
var messageLoader = function(callback){

        $scope.loaderIndicator = true;

        Conversation.loadMessages({}).$promise.then(function(data){

            $scope.loaderIndicator = false;

            if($scope.messages && $scope.messages.length > 0) {
              data.messages.forEach(function (item, index){

                $scope.messages.unshift(item);


              });

              read();

            } else {
              $scope.messages = data.messages;
              read();
            }

            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
            isMore = data.messages.length == 30;

            if(firstLoad) {
              isMore = data.messages.length == 30;
            } else {
              isMore = data.messages.length == LOAD_MSG_COUNT;
            }

            $scope.skipCount += LOAD_MSG_COUNT;

            if(firstLoad){
              scrollToBottom();
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Please share some of your code. Something like the HTML structure would be nice to know to understand your problem better and how it could be solved.

Comment: @thepio Added some code to question body.